# What is the best way to do an automated weekly export of an Oracle database to CSV, on Linux CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, oracle, csv, automation, centos

I'm building a database to house permafrost information. I would like to do weekly exports of it's tables to CSV, then upload them to a FTP site, where it can be bulk downloaded by clients.

The web server I'm looking to use is a Linux CentOS7 machine.

What is a reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

A very simple shell script. Here's an *outline* just off the top of my head. Untested, so there may be some details that need tweaking.

```
#!/bin/sh
ORACLE_SID=mydbname
ORAENV_ASK=NO
source oraenv
sqlplus / as sysdba @getcsv.sql
scp foobar.txt your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory
```

and getcsv.sql ...

```
set echo off feedback off verify off trimsp on head off lines 2048 pages 0
set colsep ','
spool foobar.txt
select * from mytable;
spool off
exit
```

Comment: If you're using 12.2 SQL\*Plus, I recommend looking into the `set markup csv on` option. It can handle commas and quotation marks inside the values.

Comment: @JonHeller - good point.  I thought I had heard of that markup option, but a quick check of the (pre 12.2) docs didn't turn it up.